# What kind of a timestamp is this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, timestamp

We are extracting data from a third-party database for export. Two of the columns are Timestamp columns with some of the values displayed below. The timestamp is supposed to represent a UTC timestamp from a GPS device. They are stored as `int` data types in an SQL Server database.

[image]

Any idea how I can convert this timestamp (e.g. 368815303) to a regular date/time? The numbers seen should be very recent - i.e. within Sept 2020 and should represent the time down to the nearest second.

Comment: [GPS time means seconds without leap seconds since 1980-01-06](http://leapsecond.com/java/gpsclock.htm). Which GPS device is it?

Comment: If it is not on the [List of Time Scales](https://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/timescales.html), it is probably proprietary.

Comment: Yes, we managed to find the base time. It seems to be a proprietary system with timestamps measured in seconds from 2008-08-08, 08:08:08

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment, you would use:

```
select dateadd(second, 368815303, '1980-01-06')
```

Based on your expectation, the base time appears to be about 2009-01-01, which suggests:

```
select dateadd(second, 368815303, '2009-01-01')
```

I am not familiar with any date/time epoch that uses that as the base time.  It might be some bespoke system.

Comment: Yes, we managed to find the base time. It seems to be a proprietary system with timestamps measured in seconds from 2008-08-08, 08:08:08.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some kind of epoch Unix timestamp.

Try this [Epoch Converter which converts timestamp to human date](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

Comment: Have tried this... For 368815303, it gives a date in 1981, which cannot be correct.